# autocomplete not working dynamically add remove row table

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

Autocomplete not working with dynamically add  multiple row. Currently, I have the two features working independently as in the autocomplete works on the first default input field and I can add new fields but the new dynamically generated fields do not have the autocomplete and I am not sure why.

Autocomplete working on first input field:

[enteFirst autocomplete Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHZUs.jpg)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 0;
  $("#add_row").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";


    cols += '<td><input type="text" placeholder="search by barcode" class="form-control" id="barcodeSearch" name="barcode[]' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" placeholder="Price" class="form-control" id="productCode" name="' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<input type="hidden" placeholder="Price" class="form-control" id="productId" name="product_id[]' + counter + '"/>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" placeholder="Price" class="form-control" id="balance_Qty" name="' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="number" placeholder="Qty" class="form-control stockoutQty" name="quantity[]' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><div class="input-group"><input type="number" class="form-control stockBalance" name="' + counter + '"readonly/><div class="ibtnDel input-group-btn"> <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div></div></td>';

    newRow.append(cols);
    $("#tab_logic tbody").append(newRow);
    counter++;
    newRow.find("#barcodeSearch").autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
        // Fetch data
        $.ajax({
          url: "{{route('getBarcodes')}}",
          type: 'post',
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
            search: request.term
          },
          success: function(data) {
            response(data);
          }
        });
      },
      select: function(event, ui) {
        // Set selection
        // Set selection
        $('#barcodeSearch').val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
        $('#barcode_id').val(ui.item.barcode); // save selected id to input
        $('#barcode').val(ui.item.barcode); // save selected id to input
        $('#productCode').val(ui.item.productCode); // save selected id to input
        $('#productId').val(ui.item.product_id); // save selected id to input
        $('#balance_Qty').val(ui.item.balanceQty); // save selected id to input
        return false;
      }
    });

    // now, initialize select2 *only* on the new row that was created
  });
  $("#tab_logic tbody").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    i -= 1
    calc();
  });
  $('#tab_logic tbody').on('keyup change', function() {
    calc();
  });
  $('.stockBalance').on('keyup change', function() {
    calc_total();
  });


});

function calc() {
  $('#tab_logic tbody tr').each(function(i, element) {
    var html = $(this).html();
    if (html != '') {
      var balanceQty = $(this).find('.balanceQty').val();
      var stockoutQty = $(this).find('.stockoutQty').val();
      var stockBalance = $(this).find('.stockBalance').val((balanceQty - stockoutQty));

      calc_total();
    }



  });
}


function calc_total() {
  stockBalance = 0;

  $('.stockBalance').each(function() {
    stockBalance += parseInt($(this).val());
  });


}

$(document).on('keyup', '#balanceCheck', function(calc_total) {
  var balanceQty = 0;

  $('.balanceQty').each(function() {
    balanceQty += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  var $field = $(this);
  var balanceCheck = parseInt($field.val());

  if (balanceCheck > balanceQty) {

    swal({
      title: 'Excess Quantity Enter!',
      type: "warning",
      text: 'Your Enter QTY Greater than Available QTY.',
      timer: 5000
    }) ? .then(
      function() {},
      // handling the promise rejection
      function(dismiss) {
        if (dismiss === 'timer') {
          console.log('I was closed by the timer')
        }
      }
    )
    $field.val("");
  }

});
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
  <thead class="table-success">
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">Barcode</th>
      <th class="text-center">Code</th>
      <th class="text-center">Stock In Hand</th>
      <th class="text-center">Stock Out Qty</th>
      <th class="text-center">Balance Qty</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id='barcode_search' class="form-control" name="barcode[]" type="text" placeholder="Search By barcode" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="productName" class="form-control" readonly />
          <input type="hidden" id="product_id" class="form-control" name="product_id[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="balanceQty" class="form-control balanceQty" readonly />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="quantity[]" class="form-control stockoutQty" id="balanceCheck" required />
        </td>


        <td>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="number" name="subTotal[]" class="form-control stockBalance" readonly />
            <div class="ibtnDel input-group-btn"> <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button"><i
                                                                    class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="col-md-12">
  <p class="pull-left">for new row press enter</p>
  <button id="add_row" class="btn btn-success pull-right"> <i class="fa fa-plus"
            aria-hidden="true"></i> </button>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
  <input class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It seems that you are using the same id for each row field: this is generally not recommended and can also confuse autocomplete